# Inconsistency in units in differential equations for 2d projectile trajectory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, dimensional-analysis

I am to solve the following two coupled second order differential equations involving the motion of a projectile. 
[image: Differential equations.]

For the $y''(t)$ differential equation, I do not understand why the "$g/m$" term is not  just "$g$". The units do not match. I emailed my professor, and she responded that the term is supposed to be "$g/m$" and not "$g$", but she did not explain why.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! When you have a minute, please take the [tour of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Also, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for quick reference. Cheers!

Comment: You are right, the gravitational force is after all mass dependent, $mg$, while the gravitational acceleration (which is even correctly named) does not depend on the mass, it is equal for all bodies before friction is applied. However, to get the reference results for the homework solution, you should take the equations as they are, even if physically wrong. Make an addendum with the physically correct results, and the reason for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, a valid line of reasoning is the following:

1. The sum $\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$ only makes sense if $x$ and $y$ have the same units.
2. Hence, the first equation yields $\frac{[x]}{\text{time}^2} = \frac{1}{\text{length}} \frac{[x]^2}{\text{time}^2}$, from which it follows that $[x] ( = [y]) = \text{length}$.
3. Using the same reasoning as in 1., it follows that the dimension of every sum component on the right hand side of the second equation must have dimension $\frac{[y]}{\text{time}^2} = \frac{\text{length}}{\text{time}^2} = [g]$.

This suffices to conclude that $\frac{g}{m}$ should be $g$.

**Note** that the mistake could also have been made in the term $\frac{C_d A \rho}{2m}$. If we assume that the term $\frac{g}{m}$ is correct after all, this implies that the dimension of the constant multiplying $\left(\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$ should have dimension $\frac{\text{mass}}{\text{length}}$. For example, a constant like $\frac{C_d A \rho}{2m^2}$ does the trick. Then, it follows that $[x] = [y] = \frac{\text{length}}{\text{mass}}$, and the dimensions of the equation are correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I never got around to responding.